# Is it mandatory to set a random_state when using RandomizedSearchCV?

Tags: scikit-learn, hyperparameter-tuning, randomized-algorithms

When I use RandomizedSearchCV, if I put the random state I always obtain the same results with the same hyperparams trainer. So, is it mandatory to use? Because in my opinion it is better to always try different combinations of hyperparams.
In general, I set the random state for the model used in RandomizedSearchCV, but not for it.
Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the results to be reproducible then yes, it is (almost surely) necessary, otherwise it is not. You might still want to use a seed when trying out different parameters/models as this will allow you to accurately evaluate the differences of these, otherwise you would not be able to tell whether the difference is because of the different models/parameters or because of different folds (so randomness).

Comment: So can I keep doing like this: model = XGBClassifier(random_state=42) and RandomizedSearchCV without random_state in order not to repeat each time the same iteration. In this way I should find the best hyperparams for the model with random_state = 42

Comment: No, the random state of XGBoost will make sure the same model will be returned each time, however randomizedsearch is a different method which has it's own seed, so you need to provide a seed to it as well. Or rather provide a seed for randomizedsearch and not for xgboost.

Comment: Yes, but if I do it RandomizedSearchCV will always try the same hyperparams combination. While if I keep it only for the XGB model the model will always be the same, while RandomizedSearchCV will try different hyperparams combinations

Comment: @FlavioBrienza You will get the same model only if the parameters and data is the same, othernise it won't be the same. Using the same seed when changing the data or parameters doesn't really matter when building the model, but having the same validation/testing set is more important.